# return a string value from post data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with a company that posts data to my server and i am receiving the xml data this way :

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{
    String xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xmlData);
}
```

But now they need me to return a value to them.

Do i return a value by posting back like they posted to me ? 
Or how does it work when i want to return a value for their post?

The value that should be returned is a string.

Project built in c#

Comment: What kind of data do you want to return? XML?

Comment: That's up to your vendor. We can't answer your question because we have no idea what inputs they accept.

Comment: Sorry, they need a string value.

Comment: @syncis You're going to need to know *much* more than just that.

Comment: @ReacherGilt True, but i just need to understand what ways there is to return data.

Comment: @servy Actually Response.Write("String") worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return any kind of string to your vendor, try something like this :

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{
    String xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xmlData);
    Response.Write("MyString");
}
```

Specify whatever in "MyString" as per need.

Answer (score 0):

You have included the tag asp.net-mvc-3 in your question, so i guess you are in a controller.
If you want to return a simple string just use the `Content` method:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    return Content("Your String")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to return a simple type, such as an integer, string or true/false, then it should be sufficient to simply use:

```
Response.Write(returnVal);
```

Or similar.  This isn't necessarily the "correct" way to do it, and if you need to return a complex type, such as an object, then you might be best serializing it and returning it as json or XML.  Here is an example using xml as the output type on a blank aspx page:

us

```
using System;

namespace myProject
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var o=new customObject
                {
                    prop1 = "Value1", 
                    prop2 = "Value2", 
                    prop3 = "Value3"
                };
            var x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
            Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            x.Serialize(Response.Output, o);
        }
    }

    public class customObject
    {
        public string prop1;
        public string prop2;
        public string prop3;
    }
}
```

Hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i return a value by posting back like they posted to me?

No. You have to send a response.

```
Or how does it work when i want to return a value for their post?
```

All you have to do is return the proper action result from your action. For ex. you can use `ContentResult` to return a simple string and `JsonResult` to return json etc.